# Is there a way to use by-value parameters in scala macros?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

For example, I want to create a macro with this form:

```
def debug(fn: => Unit): Unit = if (doDebug) fn else ()
```

I tried the following:

```
def debug(fn: => Unit): Unit = macro debugImpl
def debugImpl(c: Context)(fn: c.Expr[Unit]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  if (doDebug) fn else reify(())
}
```

but it fails with compilation error:

```
macro implementation has wrong shape:
  required: (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(fn: c.Expr[=> Unit]): c.Expr[Unit]
  found   : (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(fn: c.Expr[Unit]): c.Expr[Unit]
  type mismatch for parameter fn: c.Expr[=> Unit] does not conform to c.Expr[Unit]
    def debug(fn: => Unit): Unit = macro debugImpl
```

If I write the type of `fn` param as `c.Expr[=> Unit]`, it obviously fails with compilation error.

I am using `scala 2.10.2`. Is there a way to achieve such a macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `c.Expr[Any]` and change the type of `fn`: `c.Expr[Unit](fn.tree)`.

```
def debug(fn: => Unit): Unit = macro debugImpl
def debugImpl(c: Context)(fn: c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe.reify
  if (true) c.Expr[Unit](fn.tree) else reify(())
}


scala> debug( println("abc") )
abc
```